# Moving from epydoc to sphinx to auto-document a simple python .py file

Tags: python, python-sphinx, epydoc

Epydoc is not working good anymore, even after applying patches, so I'm trying to move to Sphinx.

I want to auto-generate documentation from a simple python file: *test.py*

After installing and running *sphinx-quickstart-script* I copied *test.py* to the *source* folder and typed:

> sphinx-build -b html .\source .\build

But it only produces the minimiun html files, and it does not parse the *test.py* file

I'm run out of ideas.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: don't know if your question is answered, if not you can add a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include `sphinx.ext.autodoc` as an extension in your `conf.py` (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html), than you can document your module using the `.. automodule::` directive (or objects from this module with `.. autoclass::`, `.. autofunction::`, ...).

See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html

Comment: Sorry I thought that this page would notice me to my email, so I did not see your answer till now. Thanks for it!

Answer (score 1):

For auto-generating the necessary `.rst` files you can use [sphinx-apidoc](http://sphinx-doc.org/man/sphinx-apidoc.html).

This makes life much easier. So you don' t have to document each of your modules manually.

Comment: thanks man! I'll try it if I create something with Phython in the future :)